# create-next-app has some issue with packages compared with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, create-react-app

I have worked with `create-react-app` repo before. But recently I am using `create-next-app` repo for server side rendering.
I created a project with `npx create-react-app` and install a package for example `npm install react-burger-menu --save` from [github](https://github.com/negomi/react-burger-menu) and then use it in App.js. everything is working:

```
import './App.css';
import { slide as Menu } from 'react-burger-menu'

function App() {
    var styles = {
     ...
    }


    return (
    <div className="App">
      <Menu styles={styles}>
        <a id="home" className="menu-item" href="/">Home</a>
        <a id="about" className="menu-item" href="/about">About</a>
        <a id="contact" className="menu-item" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        <a className="menu-item--small" href="">Settings</a>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

but I use this package in project `npx create-next-app`:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.scss'
import {slide as Menu} from "react-burger-menu";

export default function Home() {
    var styles = {
     ...
    }
    return (
        <Menu styles={ styles } >
            <a id="home" className="menu-item" href="/">Home</a>
            <a id="about" className="menu-item" href="/about">About</a>
            <a id="contact" className="menu-item" href="/contact">Contact</a>
            <a className="menu-item--small" href="">Settings</a>
        </Menu>
    );
}
```

but it creates following error:

```
Server Error
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

this error apears almost with every package I install

Comment: can you host your project on Github or maybe somewhere else? So that I can have a little bit more context on this. As your this file looks fine.

Comment: @KartikMalik Malik for [create-react-app](https://github.com/shafaprince/test-create-react-app.git) project, it is woring. but for [creat-next-app](https://github.com/shafaprince/test-1234.git) it has issue.

Comment: It's some other code which is causing that issue. Check the [CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/68593408-create-next-app-has-some-issue-with-packages-compared-with-create-react-app-4syf5), where I simply load `react-burger-menu` and it works

Comment: @PsyGik I just run `npx create-react-app` and then `npm install react-burger-menu` and import it then use it. no other code. So I assume `create-next-app` repo has some problem. but when I create next/react manually `npm i next react react-dom` or sandbox it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create next app using `npx create-next-app` it creates your project inside a folder (default `my-app`). So before installing any package (or init git) you need to run `cd my-app` (in Git bash terminal) to be in project directory. otherwise it will create a new package.json in the wrong directory.